# Why can't I get track titles from url?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to write a python script that uses BeautifulSoup to scrape the track titles from this [Interent Archive page](https://archive.org/details/HQSherlockRathboneTCS). I'd like to be able to output:

391106 - Bruce-Partington Plans
   400311 - The Retired Colourman
   ...

But I am unable to find the tags.  Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import getopt, sys
# screen scraping stuff
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def usage ( msg ):
        print """
usage: get_titles_sherlockholmes_basil.py

%s
""" % ( msg )
#end usage

def output_html ( url ):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen( url ).read())

        #title = soup.find_all("div", class_="ttl")
        #titles = soup.find_all(class_="ttl")
        #titles = soup.find_all('<div class="ttl">')
        #titles = soup.select("div.ttl")
        #titles = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "ttl"})
        #titles = soup.find_all("div", class_="jwrow")
        #titles = soup.find_all("div", id="jw6_list")
        titles = soup.find_all(id="jw6_list")
        for title in titles:
                print "%s <br>\n" % title
# end output_html

url = 'http://archive.org/details/HQSherlockRathboneTCS'
output_html ( url )
print "<br>-------------------<br>"
sys.exit()
```

I figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the playlist is formed in the browser with the help of javascript. The actual track list is located inside a `script` tag in a javascript array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

Play('jw6', 
     [{"title":"1. 391106 - Bruce-Partington Plans","image":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/391106.png","duration":1764,"sources":[{"file":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/391106.mp3","type":"mp3","height":"0","width":"0"}],"tracks":[{"file":"https://archive.org/stream/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/391106.png&vtt=vtt.vtt","kind":"thumbnails"}]},
{"title":"2. 400311 - The Retired Colourman","image":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/400311.png","duration":1755,"sources":[{"file":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/400311.mp3","type":"mp3","height":"0","width":"0"}],"tracks":[{"file":"https://archive.org/stream/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/400311.png&vtt=vtt.vtt","kind":"thumbnails"}]},
...
{"title":"32. 460204 - The Cross of Damascus","image":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/460204.png","duration":"1720.07","sources":[{"file":"/download/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/460204.mp3","type":"mp3","height":"0","width":"0"}],"tracks":[{"file":"https://archive.org/stream/HQSherlockRathboneTCS/460204.png&vtt=vtt.vtt","kind":"thumbnails"}]}], 
     {"start":0,"embed":null,"so":false,"autoplay":false,"width":0,"height":0,"audio":true,"responsive":true,"expand4wideVideos":false,"flash":false,"startPlaylistIdx":0,"identifier":"HQSherlockRathboneTCS","collection":"oldtimeradio","waveformer":"jw-holder","hide_list":false});

</script>
```

The idea would be to locate the `script` tag with `BeautifulSoup`, use regular expressions to extract the list from the script and load it into a python list with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval
import re
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://archive.org/details/HQSherlockRathboneTCS'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

script = soup.find('script', text=lambda x: x and 'jw6' in x)
text = script.text.replace('\n', '')

pattern = re.compile(r"Play\('jw6', (.*?),\s+\{\"start")

playlist = literal_eval(pattern.search(text).group(1).strip())
for track in playlist:
    print track['title']
```

Prints:

```
1. 391106 - Bruce-Partington Plans
2. 400311 - The Retired Colourman
3. 440515 - Adventure Of The Missing Bloodstain
4. 450326 - The Book of Tobit
5. 450402 - The Amateur Mendicant Society
...
30. 460121 - Telltale Pigeon Feathers
31. 460128 - Sweeney Todd, Demon Barber
32. 460204 - The Cross of Damascus
```